# Python cant check graphviz

Tags: python, algorithm, graphviz, pydot

[CANN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddtrZ.jpg)[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evXQ2.jpg)

I have installed all required libraries including graphviz but still can't get png output (it's CANN algorithm for machine learning) help

Comment: the error says it: `pydot` is not installed. you need to install that package.

Comment: And  (according to the error message) you probably need to install the Graphviz package

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.